# When creating a Database, do we have to leave some space for just in case?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm currently creating a new database with my senior. While creating a DB, my senior created a certain field, named "Reserved" with datatype LONGTEXT, at every table. And he said the purpose of this is, if later on maybe other fields might be added, so he thought we should leave some space at the table.

Since we both are not the specialist on DB, I doubt this kind of field is appropriate. So I looked up, but there was nowhere to find the answer.

Is it okay to leave some space at each table with datatype LONGTEXT?

Comment: This would be a non-standard practice.  I don't see a reason for it.

Comment: _"I doubt this kind of field is appropriate"_  your doubts are valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the single LONGTEXT approach is it can be used for just that, but not much else. It doesn't really reserve space, just a name in a table.

`ALTER TABLE` can be used to extend the table row to future needs as they eventuate.